# Making percentages attending to group but color by another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I am trying to make a bar plot in R using ggplot. The plot is supposed to represent the percentages of different lengths, and each facet represent a categorical variable. There is a third variable by which I want to color the bars. Here is a simulation of what I am doing:

```
lengths <- sample(x = c(12, 15, 20, 25, 30, 32, 35, 40, 45, 60), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
group <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
sex <- sample(c("Female", "Male"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)

data <- data.frame(lengths = lengths, sex = sex, group = group)
rm(lengths, group, sex)

ggplot(data = data %>% 
         bind_rows(data %>% 
                     mutate(group = "Total")), aes(x = lengths, group = group, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), color = "black", stat = "count") +
  labs(y = "%", fill = "sex") +
  facet_wrap(~ group, nrow = 6, strip.position = "right", scales = "free") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20,80)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.75, .95), legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"), axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), panel.background = element_blank(), legend.direction = "horizontal", strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("purple", "blue", "gray"))
```

But the result is not what I am looking for, since all bars are colored in gray instead of filled by sex:

[image]

This is the code I used to calculate the proportion regarding the counts within each group (not sex). If I do not account for the group argument the scales appear wrong.

So in essence I still want to show the proportion relative to each different group but fill the bars with the other categorical variable.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the group=group:

```
`ggplot(data = data %>% 
         bind_rows(data %>% 
                     mutate(group = "Total")), aes(x = lengths, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), color = "black", stat = "count") +
  labs(y = "%", fill = "sex") +
  facet_wrap(~ group, nrow = 6, strip.position = "right", scales = "free") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20,80)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.75, .95), legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"), axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), panel.background = element_blank(), legend.direction = "horizontal", strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("purple", "blue", "gray"))`
```

It took me quite a while to figure this out.

Comment: No, with that the percentages are not calculated in reference to the group. If you apply that change to the example, you can see how the y axis change to another percentage.

Comment: I don't suppose removing the " scales = 'free' " from the facet_wrap call is acceptable?

Comment: That does not solve it

Comment: It's beyond my knowledge, sadly, but I think the answer must involve a data transformation before calling ggplot, as it seems clear that group and fill are not compatible as you have them set up.